# Glassfish will not start

Tags: glassfish

I am installing Glassfish 3.1.2 on a vps server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS  and a I am not being able to start glassfish.

As X are not installed and I am connecting via ssh I am using the manual unzip method to install Glassfish.

Inside Glassfish bin directory with the glassfish user I do ./asadmin start-domain and nothing happens.  It seems to hang. I cannot even stop it with ctrl+c. I need to kill the java process from another console.

The server.log file in the domain does not show any error. Last two lines are:

```
mar 23, 2013 1:12:03 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: Se ha iniciado correctamente en 7 mseg.
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I was installing glassfish. I fixed this problem by running Glassfish on an old version of jre. I was trying to install with version 1.8 and ended up using an old installation of jre6. Server started fine after I installed Glassfish using version 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug with the log levels. GFFileHandler logging level might be set to "OFF".

Try this:

```
asadmin start-domain
asadmin set-log-levels com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.GFFileHandler=ALL
asadmin restart-domain
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem is that server is not starting and the set-log-levels command will not execute neither:

Comment: Sometimes, when I execute the start-domain command I get this error: `Exception in thread "Reference Handler" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
        at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueue(ReferenceQueue.java:68)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:146)` And afterwards the message saying that iti is waiting for the domain to start, and timing out eventually. Any more ideas of what I cant try or wher to look for bugs.